# IO.FileSystemWatcher HDD просыпается по непонятной причине

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, hdd, sleep

Как нужно правильно написать программу для перехвата причины, по которой HDD выходит из сна? Или как написать программу мониторинга чтения файлов на диске D:?

Дополнительные детали:

HDD просыпается по непонятной причине каждые полчаса, и, так как он очень шумный, то меня это раздражает.

я написал программу для мониторинга файлов на диске D:\ c использованием `IO.FileSystemWatcher` на C#, однако ничего не работает, так как в Windows 10 отключено изменение атрибутов у файлов для `LastAccessed`. (FSUtil подтверждает)

Пример кода на WinForm.

```
this.fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
this.fileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = ((System.IO.NotifyFilters)((((System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName | System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName) 
    | System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Security | NotifyFilters.Size) 
    | System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess)));
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Path = "D:\\";
this.fileSystemWatcher1.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Changed);
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Changed);
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Changed);
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed);

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += $"{e.FullPath} {e.Name} {e.ChangeType} \n";
}
```

Comment: Вангую, что это служба обновления венды. Или индексации файлов.

Comment: Вам нужно это сделать один раз? Если так, тогда зачем писать программу, если существует Process Monitor от Sysinternals. Там можно перехватить любое обращение к диску, увидеть процесс, файл и т.д.